# What is row weight for a product?

Tags: magento-1.9

What does the `row weight` attribute for a product mean? What is the difference to normal weight?

Answer (score 0):

`row weight` isn't an product attribute is a `sales_order_item` field and represents (as it names suggest) the total row weight ie:

If you have 3 items about 3lbs each the row_wight will be 9lbs.